Is the residual variance $E(\operatorname{Var}(Y \mid \mathbf{Z}))$ equal to $\operatorname{Var}(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z])$?
For simplicity, let $Y$ and $Z$ be random variables. I understand the following law of total variance:
$$
\operatorname{Var} Y=E(\operatorname{Var}(Y \mid Z))+\operatorname{Var}(E(Y \mid Z)).
$$
In my applied statistics class, we work with straight line regression and assume it is the correct specification. That is, we assume $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z] = \beta_0 +\beta_1 Z$. There we were given an empirical observation of the above population-level fact.
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \hat Y_i)^2 +\sum_{i=1}^n (\hat Y_i - \bar{Y})^2
$$
It can be interpreted as variation of $Y=$ residual variation + variation of $Y$ explained by the straight line $\hat Y = \hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1 Z$. Moreover, we can multiply every thing by $1/n$.
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \hat Y_i)^2 +\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\hat Y_i - \bar{Y})^2
$$
I'm interested in the term $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \hat Y_i)^2$. Its corresponding population quantity seems to be
$$
\mathbb{E}[(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z])^2], 
$$
Since the mean of $Y - \mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z]$ is zero, this can be rewritten as
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z] - \mathbb{E}(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z])\right)^2\right], 
$$
which by definition is $\operatorname{Var}(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z])$.
Going back to the above law of total variance, I'm wonder if the following equality holds:
$$
E(\operatorname{Var}(Y \mid Z))= \operatorname{Var}(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z]).
$$
From the name of the residual variance, the expression $\operatorname{Var}(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z])$ is more intuitive to me than $E(\operatorname{Var}(Y \mid Z))$.
Here is what I have tried:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z]) &= E[(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z])^2] - (E(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z]))^2\\
&= E[(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z])^2]\\
&= E[E[(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z])^2\mid Z]] \quad \text{(Tower property)}\\
&= E[\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid Z)]\quad \text{(Definition of conditional variance)}
\end{align*}
May I ask is above derivation correct?

Looks good. I think error variance (slightly different than residual variance) usually refers to $\textrm{Var}(Y\mid Z)$ in regression, since most regression will fully condition on $Z$. Not sure what's the proper terminology for random $Z$ regression.

This would be a consequence of the residuals being uncorrelated with the predicted values, which is indeed the case with linear regression.  This zero correlation i.e. zero covariance then gives $\operatorname{Var} (Y-E(Y \mid Z))+ \operatorname{Var}(E(Y \mid Z)) = \operatorname{Var} Y$ and your desired result stems from the law of total variance.
